# Python math: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a matrix in python of which I'm trying to fill in some of the entries using a for loop. My vector $X$ is a five-dimensional vector with entries given by the following:

[image]

In the code below, I simply used the values I get from the alpha's and beta's instead of writing alpha and beta.

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import math
from math import factorial

def nCr(n,r):
    if r<n:
        numerator=factorial(n)
        denominator=(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r))
        answer=numerator/denominator
        return answer
    if r>n:
        return 0

X1 = np.zeros((nt,NN,5))
for i in xrange(0,5):
    X1[0,:,i] = nCr(4,i)*((.0582**i)*(.125**(4-i)))/((.0582+.125)**4)
```

However, I'm getting an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

I'm not sure what other way there is to write each vector entry in the above expression (I could compute each entry explicitly, but I'd rather use a for loop just to cut down on manual computation and it's a good learning exercise).

Comment: Your `nCr` function will return `None` when `n == r`.

Comment: Why is it so difficult, the error clearly speaks for itself. if still facing problems, try printing values at every step before doing any arithmetic.

Comment: @root Ah ok, changing r<n to r<=n seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Changing the second `if` to `else` would also be a good idea ;)

Comment: @Brenton ... or start the function with `if r >= n: return 0` and then you can follow with the real computation code.